# Thread safe OfType

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am facing the problem that this code:

```
enumerable.OfType<Foo>().Any(x => x.Footastic == true);
```

Isnt thread safe and throws an enumeration has changed exception.

Is there a good way to overcome this issue?

Already tried the following but it didnt always work (seems to not fire this often)

```
public class Foo
{
    public void DoSomeMagicWithCollection(IEnumerable enumerable)
    {
        lock (enumerable)
        {
            enumerable.OfType<Foo>().Any(x => x.Footastic == true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `enumerable` in this case? If you're trying to iterate over a collection that's fundamentally unsafe to iterate over, then you're going to have problems whatever you do. Note that `OfType` is *not* the culprit here.

Comment: This error only appears if some code *changes* the enumerable. The code you posted doesn't appear that so it should threadsafe. Where exactly do you get the exception? What is the call stack? How do you create the IEnumerable? Do you have other code that modifies the enumerable from another thread?

Comment: You need a lock object everywhere you do anything with the enumerable.  Somewhere else you are modifying the enumerable without using a lock.

Comment: @JonSkeet enumerable would be a custom list with this definition: ´ObservableSortedList<T> : IList<T>, IList, IEnumerable<T>, INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyCollectionChanged´

Comment: @Kevin you don't, if you use one of the thread-safe collections. In any case, if some other code modifies the enumerable inadvertently, the solution is to remove it, not add locks.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are correct... but if you don't know what the enumerable is you have to use locks.

Comment: @RandRandom: And presumably that collection is being changed in another thread. That's inherently safe to iterate over.

Comment: @RandRandom where is the code that *modifies* this enumerable? What is ObservableSortedList? It's not a BCL library

Comment: @JonSkeet Since the list I have is my own class would the following be enough to make it thread safe: public void `Add(T item) { lock(this) { ... } }`, so that the Add method of my list locks this instance of the collection, would than the reading be okay?

Comment: @RandRandom: Yes, that would work - but note that your `DoSomethingMagicWithCollection` method doesn't currently do anything; if you end up returning a lazily-evaluated LINQ sequence, that would have problems. Likewise if you end up doing anything long-running in the method, it would block your UI if that's trying to add to the list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're getting an exception that the underlying collection has changed while enumerating it, given that this code clearly doesn't mutate the collection itself, it means that another thread is mutating the collection while you're trying to iterate it.

**There is no possible solution to this problem other than simply not doing that**.  What's happening is that the enumerator *of the `List`* (or whatever collection type that is) is throwing the exception and preventing further enumeration because it can see that the list was modified during the enumeration.  There is no way for the enumerators of `OfType` of `Any` that wrap it to possibly recover from that.  The underlying enumerator is refusing to give them the data from the list.  They can't do anything about that.

You need to use some sort of synchronization mechanism to prevent another thread from mutating the collection wnile this thread is enumerating this collection.  Your `lock` doesn't prevent another thread from using the collection, it simply prevents any code that locks on the same instance from running.  You need to have any code that could possibly mutate the list *also* lock on the same object to properly synchronize them.

Another possibility would be to use a collection that is inherently designed to be accessed from multiple threads at the same time.  There are several such collections in the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace.  They may or may not fit your needs.  They will take care of synchronizing access to their data (to a point) on their own, without you needing to explicitly lock when accessing them.

Comment: What class from the `System.Collections.Concurrent` Namespace would you recommend to replace my current class definition of `public class ObservableSortedList<T> : IList<T>, IList, IEnumerable<T>, INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyCollectionChanged` with?

Comment: @RandRandom Considering that I have no idea what you're doing with the collection, I couldn't possibly say, which is why I didn't name a class, I simply named the namespace.  Obviously none of the collections implement all of those interfaces.